# Pinterest OAuth API - connect: connection refused - Error Code '12'

Tags: oauth-2.0, connection, pinterest

Getting below response in Pinterest OAuth Connect API response :

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 12, "data": "path: /oauth/\nparams:<dict_itemiterator object at 0x7efb64c41710>\nAuthError(code=500, message='dial tcp 127.0.0.1:22000: connect: connection refused')", "message": "Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that.", "endpoint_name": "oauth_connect"}
```

The documentation we are following is here:

https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/overview

Is there any change in this flow or any one else with same type of issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The auth flow is working fine now. Looks like they have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the same thing using the Postman application to generate a token while logged into my pinterest account.

My Error Code:

```
{"status": "failure", "code": 12, "data": "path: /oauth/\nparams:<dict_itemiterator object at 0x7f2cec58f950>\nAuthError(code=500, message='dial tcp 127.0.0.1:22000: connect: connection refused')", "message": "Something went wrong on our end. Sorry about that.", "endpoint_name": "oauth_connect"}
```

Comment: yes via postman the oauth part is not working. There is definitely some issue from Pinterest end but I was looking for some alternate option or some changes in existing api to complete the oauth flow, If possible.

Comment: I just tried postman again today and same error. XYX... when you find an alternate option to generate an access token, can you please post it here? Much appreciated.

Comment: The pinterest partner websites are still working and it seems pinterest is not in a hurry to fix this bug. Only available option for now is to apply as a partner for pinterest and then to use the partner program flow which I think is different from this one.

Comment: What about the Pinterest Javascript SDK? From the docs it looks like you don't need access token.

Comment: The Javasript SDK is giving invalid APP Id error to me. And Pinterest has also announced in there app section that they are deprecating the developer API. And are in beta for New API. But this is not professional behavior that there new API are in Beta and they have deprecated old one.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Pinterest is depracting the developer API]

Pinterest is depracting the developer API.